# EDMessage.framework error

Tags: cocoa, xcode4, frameworks

I linked my MacOS project to the EDMessage.framework. Now I get this error:

```
Apple Mach-O Linker (Id) Error:

in /Users/.../EDMessage 17/EDCommon.framework/EDCommon, truncated fat file. Slice from 847872 to 1189136 is past end of file with length 1048576 for architecture x86_64
```

Any idea how to resolve this?

(I using Xcode 4.3.2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A similar issue is being discussed on the "official" forum: http://www.mulle-kybernetik.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=273